# how to insert large number of data in multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form which have two portion, one is for information and second one is the long list of feature that user can check. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<h1> Basic Info </h1>
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="text" name="city" />
<input type="text" name="location" />
<input type="text" name="type" />
<h1> Features </h1>
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
<input name="feature" type="radio" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have two tables (p_detail and p_feature), I want that user basic information insert in p_detail table and feature insert in p_feature table. 
my p_feature table have following column, (id, property_id, features) and my p_detail have(id, title,location,city and so on.) the main problem is in p_feature table, I want id in p_detail should be the same in property_id in p_feature. How could I do this??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assume the 'id' is incremental primary key in p_deatil,

After insert 'p_detail', you get the insert_id like,

```
$id_p_detail = $mysqli->insert_id;
```